# FusionAuth OTP Oauth Login

Tags: oauth-2.0, one-time-password, fusionauth

Is there any way to use OTP in Fusion's Oauth login page? I don't want to users to enter their password in login page, instead I want to send them an OTP via SMS.

I have already implemented OTP login using fusion's jwt api, the problem is I want to have SSO between different domains without username/password, but with phone number/otp and I don't think jwt is the way here.

The solution I have in mind is to manage sessions myself, but I don't know if this is a safe way to go or not. I'd appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way, you can get a code using passwordless-login API and the redirect user to `/oauth2/passwordless/[passwordlesscode]?redirect_uri=[redirect URI]&response_type=code&client_id=[client_id]`.

The original solution and more details are available [here](https://fusionauth.io/community/forum/topic/333/passwordless-oauth).